# connection between "connection" and "torah"

Tags: sources-mekorot, rishonim, gematria-numerology

I have seen qouted in the name of Rebbi Avrohom son of Rambam that קשורה has the same numerical value as תורה [an idea also quoted in Bal Haturim Vayigash 44 30]. I'd appreciate if anyone could direct me to the source of this Rebbi Avrohom in one of his Seforim.

Comment: if you like an answer, consider marking it correct.

Answer (score 2):

בעל הטורים (ויגש מד ל) קשורה. בגימטריא תורה. שלמד מפיו תורה: קשורה. ב' במסורת. הכא ונפשו קשורה בנפשו. ואידך אולת קשורה בלב נער (משלי כב טו). שאמר לו שהוא נער ואף אם לקח הגביע, מפני אולתו שקשורה בו. אי נמי מפני שאולתו קשורה בו, צריך שתהא נפשו קשורה בנפשו של אביו כדי לחנכו:

בפי' ר' אברהם בן הרמב"ם על התורה (ריש פרשת ויגש) כתוב "ונפשו קשורה בנפשו קשורה עולה בגימטריא תורה כלומר שחבוב הוא עליו לפי שהוא מלמדו תורה ואוהב אותו על ענין הלימוד כנפשו"

I always quote the following following statement!!!

בס' הקנה ד"ה ענין יראת המקום "ובאמת בני אפילו למד ספרא וספרי וכולהו תלמודא עם הארץ יקרא אצל החכם כי החכם נקרא שנפשו קשורה נפשה של תורה"

Answer (score 2):

The editor of Rabbenu Avraham ben HaRambam's commentary to the Torah writes that this comment, found in Vayigash (44:30) was demarcated and identified in the manuscript as an errant comment that found its way into the text.

Comment: so who wrote it? certainly had a calculator!

Comment: @rabbi as you noted in the question, this Gematriya was floating around, I assume that the original author was familiar with it from the Baal HaTurim, or some other source.